# Regex to match content of HTML options

Tags: php, regex

**NB: Please use DOM parsers if you are able to use them in your project, use regex only on edge cases.**

I need to get an array with the content of each option, this is my HTML:

```
<option value="2" selected>none</option>
<option value="1">fronttext</option>
<option value="15">fronttext,frontpicture</option>
```

I need to get:

```
["none", "fronttext", "fronttext,frontpicture"]
```

I'm using this regex:

```
<option.*>(.*)<\/option>
```

But when I use it in PHP with:

```
preg_match_all('/<option.*>(.*)<\/option>/', $string, $matches);
```

It matches only the last result (`"fronttext,frontpicture"`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regex isn't really the best way to parse HTML (although you would have better luck using it with XHTML). I would recommend using a DOM parser instead.

Comment: I can't, I'm hacking an old code, no other solutions. Regex here is just fine.

Comment: What's wrong ? your regex is producing the required result on `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
<option.*?>\K.*?(?=<\/option>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sW4lA5/1)

Code would be,

```
preg_match_all('~<option.*?>\K.*?(?=<\/option>)~', $string, $matches);
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<'EOT'
<option value="2" selected>none</option>
<option value="1">fronttext</option>
<option value="15">fronttext,frontpicture</option>
EOT;
preg_match_all('~<option.*?>\K.*?(?=<\/option>)~', $mystring, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
            [1] => fronttext
            [2] => fronttext,frontpicture
        )

)
```

Comment: yo don't need a capturing group. `\K` dirscards all the previous matches, and lookahead asserts that the following string must be `</option>`. So the text within the tags are matched. `print_r($matches)` stores the matched strings in an array. It gives first preference to the groups and then the matches. In mine, there is no group so the matched strings are stored in an array.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `.*` in your regex which is by nature *greedy*.

Try this regex:

```
preg_match_all('~<option[^>]*>([^<]*)</option>~', $string, $matches);
```

However as a word of caution I suggest you to look into using DOM parser instead of regex for parsing HTML/XML text.

Comment: But his `regex` is producing the desired result on `$matches[1]` and your regex also giving the same. So whats Difference ?

Comment: Difference is use of `.*` in OP's regex which is greedy in nature.